# How can I move one border down

Tags: html, css

I want to move div `.container` down. I tried using (margin-top: 30px) is working but it moves down the border of (.container) down together with `outline` of `.all`. I want the border of `.container` to be the only one that is moved down:

```css
.all {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 100vh;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 600px;
  width: 335px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give some padding

Answer (score 1):

Using `transform` instead. For absolute distance you want, `translate` is the good choice. For this situation `tranform: translateY(*px)` is the way.

Btw we can combine `position` with `top left bottom right` too.

use `position: relative` at parent node to mark the spot to using `top/left`.

use `position: absolute` at the node you want to move and `top: 30px` to move it down 30px from parent node

```css
.all {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 100vh;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 600px;
  width: 335px;
  transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
.container {position: relative; top: 30px;}
```

or:

```
.all {padding-top: 30px;}
```

Comment: The second one worked